# Laptop keeps restarting

Tags: laptop, reboot, cmos

I switched the internal graphics device to disabled or enabled, I cant remember which one, but then laptop just keeps restarting and seems to be dead! I cleared the CMOS and started again but it made no difference!

The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q with RAM upgraded to 8gb, CPU upgraded to i5 3210M, and storage upgraded to SSD.

EDIT: AFTER START IT TURNS OFF AND START ITSELF AGAIN, BUT IT KEEPS RUNNING, BUT STILL WITH SCREEN NOT LIGHTED

Comment: If it restarts it's not dead, that's a good thing. Could you please provide more information on your system?

Comment: Start in Safe Mode (press F8 repeatedly) and start in that mode. Then change your graphics driver settings

Comment: at what point does it restart - during boot - after boot - 5 minutes after usage?

Comment: @Smock The screen doesnt even light, when I start it, it runs like few seconds, stops and starts again

Comment: How long did you remove the cmos battery for? (are you *sure* it was the cmos battery?

Comment: @Smock Its been exactly 10 minutes + I dont know, but I didnt see any other one, and on youtube a guy replaced the same

Comment: How long was the battery out of the laptop before you put it back in? (You have put it back in haven't you?)

Comment: Both battery and cmos for 10 minutes @Smock

Comment: @John my screen is not lightening up, so...

Comment: Please add the laptop make/model/details to the question?

Comment: Maybe try installing the prior BIOS from a bootable USB or CD

Comment: How do I do that? @John

Comment: Lenovo Support Site for the BIOS tells you how to make bootable media but you need the prior BIOS.

Comment: I have only windows installer @John

Comment: Added what you needed @Smock

Comment: @Arty When you say your computer runs, does the screen show something ?
If it was an internal graphics issue, trying to connect an external monitor to your laptop could resolve it by triggering the dedicated GPU driver. You should have a Radeon HD 7610M GPU in your laptop.

Comment: @Menkid Aint sure, my laptop keeps restarting so

Comment: @Arty please double check you put the CMOS battery back correctly.
Then you can try to boot in [safe mode](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/start-toshiba-laptop-safe-mode-43682.html)
If pressing F-keys on startup doesn't do anything, you may try to install the prior BIOS (but I would rather call the tech support...)

Comment: BTW I meant Toshiba Site - Not Lenovo. My error there

Comment: Did you try attaching an external monitor as @Menkid suggested ?

Comment: [Suggestion here](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/33273/My+Toshiba+laptop+powers+up,+but+the+screen+is+black.) suggests to power it on by holding *shift + F8 + power button*. There's slight variations around doing with battery in / out, so try them all.

Comment: @Smock but it is hard to do that, coz it shutdowns

Comment: @Smock I think I will go and just buy a new motherboard